# What Are the Implications of the Destiny Reporting System

Tags: destiny

Within Destiny you can report players.  At first I thought this was for only negative feedback but after using it to report someone for a negative thing I found out that you can report people for positive behavior as well.

I searched around and was unable to find whether any amount of reporting (good or bad) actually has an affect on the players you're reporting.  If anyone knows what the implications of the reporting system is I would welcome the information.

I am playing Destiny on the PS4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been rumored that during a game, reporting a player for a negative reason will decrease your likely-hood of seeing the same player again, (possibly not at all) and reporting a player for a positive reason will increase your likely-hood of seeing the same player in the event.

It worked that way in Halo, made by the same company.

Destiny said:

> Send in-game player reports, even positive ones! We want to know when a player is particularly helpful or skilled, and making a positive impact on the world of Destiny!

So I assume that a player report will be directly read by the support team, not entirely ignored.

**It may also be possible that a player might be elected for a moderator if he gets a lot of positive reports.**

[Source 1](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/704532-destiny/70138723)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I had heard similar rumors like this one as to what the effect was for reporting.  Hopefully Bungie can come out with an official explanation at some later point in time.  I think if leveraged properly this could be a system that really improves the game for everyone.  It would also be nice to be able to see a list of recent players you've come in contact with so you can report them (good or bad) after you've disbanded from them.

Comment: Can you link to your source, and back up what reporting does?  We try not to use rumors for answers here.

Comment: @Frank Here you go: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/704532-destiny/70138723

Comment: I'm not really seeing anything in there that's at all authoritive.  It's just guessing what might be happening.

Comment: @Frank The problem with the question is that there is no information from any authority about what is really going on. We can only speculate.

Comment: Yeah, I get that.  Unfortunately, we really don't want answers to just speculate on what might be happening or not.  Just repeating rumors doesn't help us clarify or explain what's actually going on, I'm afraid.

Comment: But it can clarify what might be going on. In my opinion that is all that matters for questions that have no definite answers.